# Programmatically create SessionFactory in Spring

Tags: spring, sessionfactory

Suppose I **programmatically** create a AnnotationSessionFactoryBean and set the various properties correctly. How can I then extract the Hibernate SessionFactory, since all methods that pertain to creating the SessionFactory are protected?

```
AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = sessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(); // Protected!!
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `getObject()`, after calling `afterPropertiesSet()`:

```
sessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
```

(`AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` implements `FactoryBean<SessionFactory>`)

Be careful, though: by doing this, it becomes your responsibility to make sure the `SessionFactory` is closed when you're finished with it.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I tried it and it just returns null. It seems apparent that the sessionFactoryBean has not yet "created" the SessionFactory and that it requires this creation process to be completed before calling getObject(). I notice that there is none of the expected console output that would occur whilst initialising the SessionFactory.

Comment: @user791160: Ah yes, good point... see edit regarding `afterPropertiesSet`